# General Method of Parameterisation for Differentiating under Integral Sign

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative, self-learning

I am having difficulties differentiating under integral signs.

Is there a general way of parameterising the expression?
Like with trig substitutions, there are general substitutions you should make in certain situations. **Is there something like that for the differentiation method?**
Because in my opinion, it is not until I have differentiated, and tried u substitution or partial integration, do I realise that my choice of a parameter was incorrect.

Comment: Do you have a certain example in the mind?

Comment: Well if I were to give you one, it's a seemingly simple looking one (and I want to use the differentiation method specifically):  $$\int_{1}^{10}\sqrt{1+cx^2}\,dx$$, where c is a constant. Now the limits of that integral, I just made up for convenience. *Note*: I can figure this out using traditional methods, however, the point of this is solely practice.